# Agora integration on Angular getting "CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "

Tags: angular, agora.io

I am a newbie in Angular. I am creating a demo app for POC. Mainly integration of Agora sdk on Angular for video call. I have got agora integration code for angular from github and implemented as follows, where `startCall()` method called on a button click :

```
startCall() {
    this.agoraService.client.join("00665c104a669ec101896fa4eaIjvT3g0EdH+Gc6qCPd063IEz/sstOTIVvMejjP6HYMoU", 'TestChannel', null, (uid) => { 
      this.localStream = this.agoraService.createStream(uid, true, null, null, true, false);
      this.localStream.setVideoProfile('720p_3');
      this.subscribeToStreams();
    });
  }

private subscribeToStreams() {
    this.localStream.on("accessAllowed", () => {
      console.log("accessAllowed");
    });
    // The user has denied access to the camera and mic.
    this.localStream.on("accessDenied", () => {
      console.log("accessDenied");
    });

    this.localStream.init(() => {
      console.log("getUserMedia successfully");
      this.localStream.play('agora_local');
      this.agoraService.client.publish(this.localStream, function (err) {
        console.log("Publish local stream error: " + err);
      });
      this.agoraService.client.on('stream-published', function (evt) {
        console.log("Publish local stream successfully");
      });
    }, function (err) {
      console.log("getUserMedia failed", err);
    });

    this.agoraService.client.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("Got error msg:", err.reason);
      if (err.reason === 'DYNAMIC_KEY_TIMEOUT') {
        this.agoraService.client.renewChannelKey("", () => {
          console.log("Renew channel key successfully");
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("Renew channel key failed: ", err);
        });
      }
    });

    this.agoraService.client.on('stream-added', (evt) => {
      const stream = evt.stream;
      this.agoraService.client.subscribe(stream, (err) => {
        console.log("Subscribe stream failed", err);
      });
    });

    this.agoraService.client.on('stream-subscribed', (evt) => {
      const stream = evt.stream;
      if (!this.remoteCalls.includes(`agora_remote${stream.getId()}`)) this.remoteCalls.push(`agora_remote${stream.getId()}`);
      setTimeout(() => stream.play(`agora_remote${stream.getId()}`), 2000);
    });

    this.agoraService.client.on('stream-removed', (evt) => {
      const stream = evt.stream;
      stream.stop();
      this.remoteCalls = this.remoteCalls.filter(call => call !== `#agora_remote${stream.getId()}`);
      console.log(`Remote stream is removed ${stream.getId()}`);
    });

    this.agoraService.client.on('peer-leave', (evt) => {
      const stream = evt.stream;
      if (stream) {
        stream.stop();
        this.remoteCalls = this.remoteCalls.filter(call => call === `#agora_remote${stream.getId()}`);
        console.log(`${evt.uid} left from this channel`);
      }
    }); 
  }
```

On browsing http://localhost:4200/ or http://192.168.43.152:4200/ from chrome the apps runs fine, but its console always prints the following, and nothing happened on button click:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cds-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1?action=config' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST https://cds-ap-web-1.agora.io/api/v1?action=config net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cds-ap-web-4.agoraio.cn/api/v1?action=config' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST https://cds-ap-web-4.agoraio.cn/api/v1?action=config net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cds-ap-web-2.agoraio.cn/api/v1?action=config' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST https://cds-ap-web-2.agoraio.cn/api/v1?action=config net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=session_init' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=session_init net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=_config-distribute-request' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=_config-distribute-request net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?eventType=join_choose_server net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=checkSystemRequirements' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=checkSystemRequirements net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=createClient' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=createClient net::ERR_FAILED
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=Client.init' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=Client.init net::ERR_FAILED
6[Violation] 'setInterval' handler took <N>ms
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=Client.join' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
zone-evergreen.js:2863 POST http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080/events/message?apiName=Client.join net::ERR_FAILED
```

I am unable to figure out how to resolve that **CORS policy** (or any other if exists) problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: mmm i think you can try to prox your request, so the angular apps even call himself, at localhost:4200, then the proxy send the request to another endopoint...[here](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Comment: I have tried that too, but no success. The proxy config which I have used `{"*":{"target":"http://localhost:4200", "secure":false, "logLevel":"debug" }}`

Comment: the target shoulde be http://webcollector-1.agora.io:6080, if i understand wll your purpose

Comment: Proxy config given on compile time, compile log shows config applied successfully, but nothing changed.

Comment: @SwarajSatvaya How did you fixed this can you please help me?

Comment: @ManishPatidar Actually I can't, So the work around is agora has its own mechanism to connect with backup server that does not produce CORS policy error. But those servers are very slow. So, The connection with the agora server must have to be a part of back end server (where browser is not involved). Other way around is disabling CORS policy by using browser plugin, but that is only for development environment.

Answer (score 0):

So Agora only allows requests from a server that have CORS enabled (security protocol).

Hence when you're serving the angular webapp, make sure you have CORS enabled.

You can check out: [This](https://www.code-sample.com/2015/02/enabling-cors-in-angularjs.html) to find out how to enable CORS on your side.

or, you can host the angular app on a [node.js server](https://dev.to/saadabbasi/do-you-want-to-run-angular-app-on-the-node-js-server-2a62) which will bypass the CORS error, since it's a server side request and not from the front-end :)